# React app (made with create-react-app) isn't parsing component

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React app (made with create-react-app) that contains the following component:

```
import React from 'react'; 

const Sample = () => {
 return (<h1>Some sample text.</h1>);
}

export default Sample;
```

However, when I run npm run start, I receive the error below:

```
Users/blah/blah/blah/blah/node_modules/babel-
core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:590
5:27:45 PM api.1 |        throw err;
5:27:45 PM api.1 |        ^
5:27:45 PM api.1 |  SyntaxError: 
/Users/blah/blah/blah/blah/my_app/src/components/sux.jsx: Unexpected token (4:12)
5:27:45 PM api.1 |    2 | 
5:27:45 PM api.1 |    3 | const Sample = () => {
5:27:45 PM api.1 |  > 4 |     return (<h1>Some sample text</h1>);
5:27:45 PM api.1 |      |             ^
5:27:45 PM api.1 |    5 | }
5:27:45 PM api.1 |    6 | 
5:27:45 PM api.1 |    7 | export default Sample;
5:27:45 PM api.1 |      at Parser.pp$5.raise ( ... and so on
```

Why is this not parsing correctly? I've included the return, I've removed it, I've changed the markup -- it all causes the same error.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

UPDATE:

This parses fine:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Sample = () => {
 return ("wtf?");
}

export default Sample;
```

Why is it parsing a string but not html markup?

Comment: What version of node & npm are you running?

Comment: Node v6.11.1 and npm 5.6.0.

Comment: Can you put your code on github or a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) where we can see the complete code.

Answer (score 2):

Did you import React in your Sample file? `import React from 'react';`
Every component that uses jsx has to import React to it.

Comment: I did import React.

Comment: Please check whether you put '"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react"
    ]
  }' in your package.json file.

Comment: Also your .babelrc file should include "presets": [
        "react"
      ],

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by I explicitly added babel-preset-react. However, it seems so odd to me insofar as all of my other jsx components in my app were not throwing this parsing error.

Any ideas?

Thanks to all of you for your help!